# how do I deny php from accessing root directory?

Tags: php, linux, bash, server, debian

I have created a service in which users can have their own directory on my webpage (http://mywebsite.com/username/) and run php on it, but currently it is possible to make php code to access root directory (http://mywebsite/) and change things there.

I have made a bash script which creates a user, disables shell from it, and gives it the username directory and ftp access to it's directory.
Is there anything I can do to avoid users from accessing root through php?

I am running a LAMP stack with linux debian

Comment: redirect root directory to desire page.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu but how?

Comment: use .htaccess for url rewrite, if you have no idea , search it or learn regular expression, regular grammar .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: `.htaccess` is read by the web server and can prevent HTTP requests to a secured directory, but it cannot prevent PHP scripts from accessing any directory themselves.

Comment: then he can put redirect url in `index.php` page .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: A redirect in `index.php` does not prevent PHP code from modifying files in any directory. Redirects are only there for HTTP clients, but we are talking about `fopen()` calls from PHP scripts, for example.

Comment: Put permissions on the root directory that aren't allowed to be read from the php user? such as 0400

Comment: @MichaelJaros any solution from your side ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: I understand why you are asking like that, and of course it is easier to tell what is *not* a solution. But it would require some more time to suggest something good here. Also, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow because it is not about programming or programming tools. The OP should ask on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) instead where they are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Are you running your apache server with the root user?

Comment: @MichaelJaros how you took it , no idea, but I would love to learn as I believe you will be also interested and the question is in wrong place is giving us profit to learn.